# ionic cordova Barcode Scanner only QR Code

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode, qr-code

I use cordova barcode scanner to integrate QR_CODE in an application.

But often, when I scan a QR Code the barcode scanner found an UPC_E code. I must to re-scan the QR Code to find it.

As of now, I use the following code to re-scan automatically (but it's not clear for my users and it's an ugly solution) :

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
        if (imageData.format == "QR_CODE") {
            // Business code for QR Code
        }
        else {
            return $scope.scanBarcode();
        }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
};
```

Do you know a way to force barcode scanner scan only QR_CODE and ignore others code ?

I don't find anything in the doc.

Comment: Any solution???

Comment: No, I didn't find anyone :'(

Answer (score 1):

there is an options for `scan()` function, you can set format to scan some kind of code.

The formats are:
'QR_CODE' | 'DATA_MATRIX' | 'UPC_E' | 'UPC_A' | 'EAN_8' | 'EAN_13' | 'CODE_128' | 'CODE_39' | 'CODE_93' | 'CODABAR' | 'ITF' | 'RSS14' | 'RSS_EXPANDED' | 'PDF417' | 'AZTEC' | 'MSI'